# Why does Session start after page logoff?

Tags: asp.net, session

I am working on an ASP.NET website, and trying to track active Sessions.

I write to a log file whenever a session is created or ended via the Session_OnStart and Session_OnEnd events.

What I am noticing, is that when a user navigates to the webpage, it creates a Sessions with a Session Id for that user, like I expect, but when the user selects to log off, and gets redirected to the homepage, the Session_OnEnd is fired, but immediately after that, the session Session_OnStart is fired with the same SessionID.

Why is this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but probably because the session for the authenticated user is destroyed and a new one created for the now anonymous user.

Comment: I thought that might be it, but the SessionID is the same for all three events, i.e. the initial session creation, the session end, then the new session start.

Answer (score 0):

Since the previous session ends, its ID is no longer valid (it does not matter if an end-user is logged in or not). As described in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524798(v=vs.90).aspx):

> A new session automatically starts whenever the server receives a request that does not contain a valid SessionID cookie.

So, a new session starts for this user as soon as any his/her request is received after session expiration.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524776(v=vs.90).aspx) says.

> A browser that does not support cookies does not return the SessionID
>   cookie, the server creates a new session each time the user requests a
>   page. Thus, for each request, the server processes the Session_OnStart
>   script and redirects the user to the starting page.